# git-subtree checkout specific folder under other name

Tags: git, git-subtree

Hi I'm trying to setup a git-repo with two upstreams.

- upstream-jointswp: (https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/)

  - The entire root-folder / goes to my repo at root /. (no problem)
- upstream-woocommerce: (https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce)

  - The subdir of this repo /templates should go under /woocommerce in my repo.
  - I was able to achive that the /templates goes as only folder/tree in my repo by using a sparseCheckout.
  - I try to use git-subtree to keep track of the commits.

When I use git-subtree. How do I checkout the stuff at /templates from my upstream to /woocommerce in my repo?

*If my question isn't as straigth forward as I hope, plz give me a sign ;)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should combine the `split` and `add`.

So, you clone the project you want part of and then create a branch in it which will contain the `templates/`. I.e.

```
git subtree --prefix=templates/ split -b templates_only
```

Then you could use the branch from another repo:

```
git subtree --prefix=woocommerce/ add ../woocommerce_clone/.git templates_only
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works.
But is a pain looked at from performance-side.
There are 5k+ commits in the subdir that gets rehashed.
It takes forever to do the split.
Is there a way to speed it up or should I use git-submodule instead?

Comment: @termnml Could submodule do it? I doubt. As I understand you have no choice, the split should go through all commits and see which of them affect the subdir. The only good thing with `split` - you need to do it only once, then you could subtree pull/push much quicker.

Comment: Thank you very much for the headsup. ;)